# Ezpublish - Why can't users search in site if not logged in?

Tags: php, ezpublish

I have taken over admin to a ezpublish 2014-6 site. Before when you tried to search there was a popup for login. If one is logged in the search works fine. I have removed that popup now but still I can not search if I am not logged in. I am always taken to the home page if I search and not logged in. I guess this must be some logic in a template but do not know where to look. Or is there a setting in the site.ini.append.php in the override folder that I missed? Or is the search restricted from the user pages in admin? I can not find anything there for controlling searching. 
~asle

Comment: ...or just check permissions.

Comment: Have you checked the policies for the Anonymous Role? Please make sure that the "content/read" is enabled for the Sections you are searching in, and also the search module, if applicable (I'm currently looking at a client project of mine and am not sure if this is a default module or not).

Comment: I have 3 sites on this ezp installation and same settings for all sections for all sites so there must be something else going on. I am trying to find out.